# Properties of Orthonormal Systems and Projections

Tags: functional-analysis, orthonormal, orthogonality

Let $\{e_1, ... , e_n\}$ be a finite orthonormal system in an inner product space $(E, \langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle)$, let $F :=$ span$\{e_1, ... , e_n\}$ and let $P:E \to F$ be the orthogonal projection onto $F$. Show that the following assertions hold:

a). $PPf = Pf$ for all $f \in E$.

b). If $f,g \in E$ are such that $g \in F$ and $f-g \perp F$, then $g=Pf$.

c). Each $f \in E$ has a **unique** representation as a sum $f=u+v,$ where $u \in F$ and $v \in F^{\perp}$.

d). If $f\in E$ is such that $f \perp F^{\perp}$, then $f\in F$. Put differently: $(F^{\perp})^{\perp} = F$

e). Let $Qf := f-Pf, \quad f \in E$. Show that $QQf=Qf$ and $\| Qf \| \leq \|f\|$ for all $f \in E$.

I am working with the following definitions:

Two elements $f,g \in E$ are called **orthogonal**, written $f \perp g$, if $\langle f, g \rangle=0$.

Let $I$ be any nonempty index set. A collection of vectors $(e_j)_{e \in I}$ in an inner product space $E$ is called an **orthonormal system** if

$\langle e_i, e_j \rangle = \delta_{ij} := \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       1 & : i=j,\\
       0 & : i \neq j
     \end{array}
   \right.  $

The mapping $P: E \to E, \quad Pf = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \langle f,e_j \rangle e_j$ is called the **orthogonal projection** onto the subspace $F$.

I have been trying to use the given definitions to proceed, but I find that I am getting nowhere fast. 
As always, any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

By the way, I am using the textbook *Functional Analysis An Elementary Introduction* by Markus Haase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

(a) $Pe_j=e_j$ for all $j$ implies $Pf=f$ for $f\in F$. 
(b) If $(f-g) \perp F$, then $(f-g,e_j)=0$ and $P(f-g)=0$ by definition. Also use (a) 
(c) $f = Pf+(f-Pf)$. Let $u=Pf$ and $v=f-Pf$. If $u,u'\in F$, $v,v' \perp F$ with $u+v=u'+v'$ then $(u-u')=(v'-v)$ is orthogonal to itself.
(d) Use (c) to decompose $f=u+v$. Show $u \perp F^{\perp}$ so $f-u = v$ is orthogonal to itself.
(e) Use (a) and Pythogorean theorem: $\|x\|^{2}=\|x-Px\|^{2}+\|Px\|^{2}$.

Comment: For your hint on (a), does replacing $e_j$ with $f$ give the desired result? If I am not mistaken, the $e_j$ is a unit vector. How does this imply that $Pf=f$? Thanks for your hints, they are greatly appreciated. I apologize if I ask many questions; this is my first time taking a course in Functional Analysis.

Comment: @Jamil_V : You're welcome. Hints are good when you're getting started. If $Pe_{j}=e_{j}$ then $P(\sum\alpha_{j}e_{j})=\sum\alpha_{j}e_{j}$; because every $f \in F$ can be written as such as sum, then it follows that $Pf=f$ for all $f \in F$.

Comment: Ok, so because of this property that $f \in F$ can be written as a sum (as in part (c)?), then what exactly is the $\alpha_j$ in your expression?

Comment: @Jamil_V : Arbitrary scalars. The sum $\sum\alpha_{j}e_{j}$ is an arbitrary linear combination of the $\{ e_{j} \}_{j=1}^{n}$; $F$ is defined as the set of such arbitrary linear combinations.

Comment: My apologies for responding so late, I got busy with other assignments and am barely getting back to this one. For, part (d), I am trying to show that $f-u=v$ is orthogonal to itself by the definition involving the inner product. I have that $u=Pf$ and $v=f-Pf$. Given that $f \perp F^{\perp}$, then $u+v \perp F^{\perp}$. This in turn means that $Pf + (f-Pf) \perp F^{\perp}$. Expanding these out by using the definition of $Pf$, I find that I didn't get much other than rewrite the same expression differently. Is there something that I am missing? Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: @Jamil_V : Because $f \perp F^{\perp}$ and $u \perp F^{\perp}$, then $f-u \perp F^{\perp}$. However $v=f-u$ and $v \in F^{\perp}$. Therefore $v \perp v$ which gives $v=0$ and $f=u \in F$.

Comment: Using part (a), I think I was able to show that $QQf=Qf$ for the last part of this problem. However, how exactly does one use Pythagorean  Theorem to show $||Qf|| \leq ||f||$? I tried the following: $||Qf|| = ||f-Pf||$. Squaring both sides, we obtain $||Qf||^2 = ||f-Pf||^2$. This is where I am stuck since I am unsure about how to expand this square norm or how to proceed in general. Thank you for your patience, I am very grateful for you assistance on this problem.

Comment: @Jamil_V : You didn't like my hint? $f=(f-Pf)+Pf$ is an orthogonal decomposition; so $\|f\|^{2}=\|f-Pf\|^{2}+\|Pf\|^{2}$, which gives $\|f-Pf\|\le \|f\|$ and $\|Pf\| \le \|f\|$.

Comment: Oh ok, I get it now! I did like your initial hint. For some reason, I was trying something else and ended up getting stuck. Thank you very much for your advise, I will accept your answer. By the way, nice quote referring to Joseph Fourier. I remember doing some research on him for a project during my senior year as an undergraduate.

Comment: @Jamil_V : Thanks for the comment. Fourier was such a character. He invented so many new things, and upset so many people. Much of modern, rigorous analysis was invented in order to address one or more of Fourier's claims. Heaviside was another one of those characters, but he was a jerk and deliberately rubbed people the wrong way. :)